# OnRender Method UserControl issue

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I want to draw a grid on UserControl on WPF, so I override OnCreate method, but grid doesn't drawing on my UserControl. 
Help please :)

```
public partial class FightField : UserControl
{
    public FightField()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        var pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(this.Height / 10 * i, 0), new Point(this.Height / 10 * i, this.Width));
            drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(this.Width / 10 * i, 0), new Point(this.Width / 10 * i, this.Height));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `this.Height` and `this.Width`, use `this.ActualHeight` and `this.ActualWidth` respectively.

PS.: I tried your code, and it only draws vertical lines for me, so there is some issue with the logic as well.

Working code:

```
drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(ActualWidth / 10 * i, 0), new Point(ActualWidth / 10 * i, ActualHeight));
drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, ActualHeight / 10 * i), new Point(ActualWidth, ActualHeight / 10 * i));
```